# Can't send json response on POST request in Spring MVC controller

Tags: json, spring-mvc, vue.js, jackson, jackson-databind

I have no trouble to send list of objects in response on POST request and receive it in VueJs client

```
@RequestMapping(value={"/data/parts"}, method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody public List<Part> getPartsList( @RequestBody LookupForm lookupForm ) {
        return getService().findParts(lookupForm.getCode(), lookupForm.getName(), lookupForm.getWarehouseCode());
}
```

But when I try to response with custom class Response (I even added `produces="application/json"` in RequestMapping annotation )

```
@RequestMapping(value={"/addPartsRequest"}, method = {RequestMethod.POST}, produces="application/json")
    @ResponseBody public Response addPartsRequest(@RequestBody PartsRequest partsRequest) {
        Response response = new Response("Fail","Your Request failed");
        PartsRequest newRequest = getService().addPartsRequest(partsRequest);
        if (newRequest != null){
            response = new Response("Ok", "The Ticket has been submitted.");
        }
        return response;
}

class Response {
    String message;
    String status;

    public Response() {
        // empty c-tor for serialization
    }

    public Response(String status, String message) {
        this.message = message;
        this.status = status;
    }
    // ... getters & setters omitted
    }
```

On VueJs side request sent with help of axios.post

```
var headers = {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
      axios.post(`${API_URL.orderApi}`, formData, {headers})
        .then(response => {
          const commitPayload = response.data.message;
          const status        = response.data.status;
          if(status === 'Ok'){
              this.$store.commit('setMessage', commitPayload)
          }else{
              this.$store.commit('setErrMessage', commitPayload)
          }
          this.$router.push('/parts')
        },
        error => {
          this.$store.commit('setErrMessage', 'Submit Order failed')
          this.$router.push('/parts')
        })
```

Vue UI client receive

```
Status Code: 406 Not Acceptable
Content-Type: text/html;charset=UTF-8
<html><head><title>Error</title></head><body>Not Acceptable</body></html>
```

Why I can respond with list of object and can't respond with POJO and how to fix the issue?
Thank you.

PS. Project depends on jackson-databind v2.8.2 and  spring v4.3.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's turns out that I was sending POST request with json body to controller mapped to url with suffix 'htm'. This request cause conflict with mime-mapping 'text/html' and as result server immediately response with code 406.

Answer (score 0):

I get the response properly when I do it from postman. I believe you have getters and setters.

use the header Accept: application/json

Mark the class as implements serializable.

Comment: Yes I mark getters and setters omitted in code snippet for clarity. And I added `class Response implements Serializable` after I post question. Still not working.

Comment: Did you try the header Accept: application/json in VueJs

Comment: I really don't understand how this ` Accept: application/json in VueJs` going to improve situation if server already responds with `406 Not Acceptable`? i.e. client side already receive error regardless it ready to accept json.

Comment: Do you have these dependencies added. <dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.13</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.13</version>
</dependency>

Comment: Thanks for help. I found reason and post answer.